# Main is internal proprietary api and may be removed in a future release

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am getting the error in line 
 `list1.setTransferHandler(new Main.MyTransferHandler());`

The error is

> Main is internal proprietary api and may be removed in a future release

how can I resolve it?

Comment: What is the full-qualified name of this `Main`? Please post the full code including imports

Comment: Usually this message is shown when using deprecated classes of third party libraries. Is your `Main` a class of a third party library?

Comment: Better to ask the higher ups (leader, cto, or whatever) how to handle deprecated that `Main` class.